# GitLab Runner on a local (beefy) Windows machine with WSL 2

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I'm willing to set up GitLab runners on my Windows machine inside a docker container/WSL 2 installation, anyone knows how to install such thing while achieving identical behavior as official GitLab auto-scaling runners?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#runner-global-options) documentation, just insert `limit = 0` inside the `[[runners]]` section of your `/srv/gitlab-runner/config/config.toml`, or wherever `config.toml` lies on your Windows machine.